# what‘s the meaning of export = and import = require()

Tags: typescript, import, export

I see a TS syntx here [export = and import = require()](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require%27)

the doc gives explaination of why TS offering this unique syntax:

> CommonJS and AMD support replacing the exports object with a custom single object. Default exports are meant to act as a replacement for this behavior; however, the two are incompatible. TypeScript supports export = to model the traditional CommonJS and AMD workflow.

so i try code here

```
//CJSmodule.ts  i try to export function by commonJS
function helloCJS(): void {
  console.log("CJSModule");
}


// export = helloCJS;
module.exports = helloCJS;
// export {helloCJS};



//index.ts
const helloCJSModule = require("./CJSModule");

//TS complains this line that it is not a module, i thought this unique syntax "import xxx = require()" is meant to compat with CommonJS's syntax like "module.exports = xxx " what's goning wrong?
import helloCJSModule1 = require("./CJSModule"); //Error CJSModule.ts' is not a module.ts(2306)
helloCJSModule1();
helloCJSModule();

export {};
```

1. Am i misunderstood this syntax? What's the point of this syntax or
   someone can gives a usecase or scenario of usage, thanks.
2. There's another question that why do i need this syntax(export = xxx
   & import xxx = require('xxx')) since i already get a more handy
   way(ES export&import) whitch is recommended by TS Doc?

Comment: I believe this is mainly for backwards compatibility and legacy workflows. There's no reason to write code today that uses that syntax in any modern typescript codebase.

Comment: I agree with that，but whether it is telling me that oh if there's a external lib witch is exporting somethings by export =  then the only way i can do to import these is to use import xxx = require?